# PhpUnit Code Coverage Does Not Work - MacOs Sierra

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug, php-7, macos-sierra

I have a project for which I write unit tests and then run them with code coverage report.

The setup on the Windows 10 machine is: PHP 7.0.2, xDebug 2.4.1, PhpUnit 5.6.1, Code coverage 4.0.1. Everything works fine, code coverage show relevant results.

Then I've cloned the same project on Mac Book with MacOs Sierra installed. Firstly I run the project on PHP 7.0.12, all other versions are the same. And as a result code coverage failed - it showed 0 in all categories.

I thought, that xDebug 2.4.1 and Php 7.0.12 are incompatible, that's why I've switched to code coverage with PhpDbg instead. With no luck unfortunately.

At last, I managed to get an old (7.0.2) PHP version through homebrew-php repository and installed it. So I got PHP 7.0.2, xDebug 2.4.1, PhpUnit 5.6.1, Code coverage 4.0.1 on MacOs Sierra. I ran the tests and got 0 in code coverage again.

So, I have completely the same setup with one difference - host OS. Can MacOs be the reason of failing code coverage? Maybe, I've missed anything else?

Comment: Ignore your main app for the time being and set up a small, standalone app with just one class, method and test. Does the code coverage *for that* work on the Mac? Maybe also compare yer composer.lock files and see if there's any other version differences you might not have noticed (longshot, but hey: easy to check).

Comment: @AdamCameron thanks for pointing out, because on a test project with a single class, single method and single test everything works, code coverage show 100%. All versions are the same, because composer.lock is the same and everything was installed from it.

Comment: @AdamCameron nevertheless I should dive deeper into configuration, maybe something incompatible there.

Comment: @AdamCameron, OMG! It's so silly, and so funny)) The reason was in directory names - they are case sensitive on unix systems, and in my config's whitelist I used lowercased names, though they have capital letters.
I've spent several hours whilst the solution took 2 seconds)

Comment: Ha! I kinda dismissed file-system casing as I only thought about the code files, and you'd've got errors if it was that. Didn't think about the whitelist! Glad you got it sorted.